# geom_boxplot, it won't let me plot my values, says they are not numeric

Tags: r

I am learning r, and I am practicing with the `rivers` built in dataset.

I want to make a boxplot of the river length `x`, but it is not working.

ex of data, full length is 141

```
x
735
320
325
392
524
450
```

my code

```
library(tidyverse)

rivers %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(y=x)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

I get this error

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

It says it is not a numeric vector so I tried using `as.numeric(x)` but that did not work. It says numeric under "x" when I view it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "x" in this data for river length is a numeric vector. You should turn it into a data frame first with `data.frame()` Also you can change the column name from "x" to avoid any issues with the `ggplot` mapping.

```
library(tidyverse)
river <- data.frame(rivers)
river %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(y = rivers)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```